# Weird Rails 3 Route Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am using simple_captcha. It worked find until I add the following line to routes.rb

```
match ":controller(/:action)", :constraints => {:controller => /sandbox\/[^\/]+/}
```

The captcha image is not showing and the log shows the following error message.

```
Started GET "/simple_captcha/8cdf70c193dc8823f281828f11c250e1739883da?time=1294644088" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Jan 09 23:21:29 -0800 2011

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action '8cdf70c193dc8823f281828f11c250e1739883da' could not be found for SimpleCaptchaController):
```

Why does the line in the routes affect simple_captcha?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume the constraint does not exist for now. Given `:controller(/:action)` matches and tries to match a particular controller and then an action, the route `/simple_captcha/8cdf70c193dc8823f281828f11c250e1739883da` matches `simple_captcha` as a controller and `8cdf70c193dc8823f281828f11c250e1739883da` as a action. You could try more of a `":controller/(:id)"` as a route matcher.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by modifying a line.

From:

```
match ":controller(/:action)", :constraints => {:controller => /sandbox\/[^\/]+/}
```

To:

```
match ":controller(/:action)", :controller => /sandbox\/[^\/]+/
```

I thought they are the same but obviously they are not. How do they differ?